# What's happening in this .then(function(reponse))?

Tags: javascript, response

Can somebody help me to understand why my **response** is empty?
With my empty response I have also the associationCheckError empty and I can't go on.

```
if (addPOs.length !== 0) {
                        requiredMetaDataAssociationCheck(addPOs, parentPO).then(function (response) {
                            var associationCheckError = response;
                            if (associationCheckError && associationCheckError.length > 0) {
                                AcknowledgeService.toastError(associationCheckError, $filter('translate')('PRODUCT.OPERATION.ADD'));
                                deferred.resolve(false);
                            }
```

Comment: Show contents of `requiredMetaDataAssociationCheck`

Answer (score 1):

If your `requiredMetaDataAssociationCheck` method is resolved to a falsy value, then you won't get into the if statement.
So make sure what `requiredMetaDataAssociationCheck` resolves to, high chances there is a case when it resolves to a falsy value.

Do not confuse resolving with returning